# Can an Eloquent model has multiple Observer?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hi I want write a trait to add an observer to model but I thought write boot method is not the right way and finnaly i find that i can boot trait like boot[TraitName] but i wonder if i add an observer with code like this:

```
trait CreateObserver
{
    public static function bootCreateObserver()
    {
        static::creating(function (Model $model) {
            // ...
        });
    }
}
```

can I add another observer for my model like below or it will overriding my trait observer?

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    use CreateObserver;
    public static function boot()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
                // ...
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why not just try it quickly yourself?

Comment: By the way, I find the question a bit misleading, because an observer is something different than listening for a single event ([see documentation on events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events)).

Answer (score 0):

That's not the right way. I think this might help you:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#observers

You bind observers to your models using a service boot:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\User;
use App\Observers\UserObserver;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        User::observe(UserObserver::class);
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Inside the observer you can add all desired functionality:

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\User;

class UserObserver
{
    /**
     * Listen to the User created event.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Listen to the User deleting event.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleting(User $user)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And to elaborate. Yes it can have multiple observers. Although I never seen a useful situation for that:

```
    public function boot()
{
    User::observe(UserObserver::class);
    User::observe(AuthenticableModelsObserver::class);

}
```

This way both the UserObserver() and AuthenticableModelsObserver() are binded to the User() model on boot.